# BGP route selection

Tags: bgp

So given the information AS A is a customer of AS B and AS E, and A is peering with AS C and AS D;
From what I understand, in the first step, we have to discard the routes with the lower local preferences. In this case, A is a customer of B, then that path has a greater local preference or lower local preference?

Below I attach the whole exercise in case I missing some important data:

[image]

Comment: The "Network Engineering" community is a better place to ask this question. It is not a programming related question.

Answer (score 0):

> From what I understand, in the first step, we have to discard the
>   routes with the lower local preferences.

Correct, one of the very first steps in the BGP best path selection algorithm is to prefer paths with the highest LOCAL_PREF (= discard paths with lower LOCAL_PREFs)

See https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/border-gateway-protocol-bgp/13753-25.html for more details.

> In this case, A is a customer of B, then that path has a greater local
>   preference or lower local preference?

It is customary to give paths received from a customer a higher LOCAL_PREF (= more preferred) than paths received from peering partners or transit providers.

See https://www.noction.com/blog/what-you-should-know-about-bgps-local_pref for more details.

Comment: Hey, a mate explained this to me, your answer is almost exactly equal as my mate told me. In this case, the path through B will have lower preference since A is customer of B :)